# Redirect a website in IIS 7.5

Tags: iis-7.5

How do I redirect a website from `www.domain1.com/en-US/example.html` to `www.domain2.com/en-US/example.html` in IIS 7?

This is what I've tried so far: [image: iis 7.5 rewrite settings]

I've also tried wildcard pattern www.domain1.com/en-US/* without a condition.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. This fixed it:

- Requested Url: Matches the pattern
- Using: Wildcards
- Pattern: en-US/*

Conditions:

- Input: {HTTP_HOST}
- Type: Matches the pattern
- Pattern: www.domain1.com
- Action type: Redirect
- Redirect URL: http://www.domain2.com/en-US/{R:1}

Hope this helps others who need to accomplish the same