# How do I redirect an IIS 7.5 url?

Tags: redirect, iis-7.5

I have a client that is migrating their website from domain1.com to domain2.com but it's not quite as simple as [an IIS 7.5 redirect](https://serverfault.com/questions/515773/redirect-a-website-in-iis-7-5) - or maybe it is and I'm not certain.

So as it stands, I have DNS for domain2.com resolving to the same public IP as domain1.com and have domain2.com bound to the IIS site and that all works.  The trouble comes after a user logs in, the webapp running on the server is hard coded to redirect the user to **sub**.domain1.com and therein lies the problem.

The source code will not currently build, so modifying the webapp to redirect to sub.**domain2**.com instead is not an option (for now).  Is there a way to intercept the 302 redirect to sub.domain1.com to sub.domain2.com instead?  Eventually we will get the source to build but time is of the essence because domain1.com is currently in escrow to be sold in the next 48 hours or so.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Comment: @LexLi, that document doesn't seem to answer the 302 redirect problem.  To clarify, after logging in, MVC redirects the browser (302) to sub.domain1.com but I need to intercept that and change it to sub.domain2.com instead.  Thoughts?

Comment: That document cannot cover all cases, but in general can help remedy most common URL redirection. However, if that web site itself binds to hard coded domain name, nothing except modifying its code can resolve the issue.